# Unexpected behavior in menu dropdown animation

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown menu with a fade bottom animation. Everything works fine but there is a problem.

Expected behavior: When I click the button to open the menu, the dropdown content is displayed with a fade animation. It works!

The problem: The animation has a certain speed, 0.4s when I click to open and 0.4s when I click to close the menu. I wish this was the speed, however I am forced to stay at 0.6s when I click to close, because below that time the animation is broken causing the dropdown to behave strangely. That is, visualize it for a moment and then it disappears.

So recap: everything works fine with `animation:animateToBottom 0.6s` but doesn't work with `animation:animateToBottom 0.4s`

all this I applied to the class `.w3-dropdown-content.w3-hide`. You can see for yourself by running the code below, the behavior is not as it should be. But if you try to change from 0.4s to 0.6s or more then it works fine.

Sorry but I'm new, did I do something wrong? I appreciate any response, thanks.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("Demo");
  if (x.className.indexOf("w3-show") == -1) {
    x.className += " w3-show";
  } else { 
    x.className += " w3-hide";
    setTimeout(function(){
    x.className = x.className.replace(" w3-show", "");
      x.className = x.className.replace(" w3-hide", "");
      
    },500)
  }
}
```

```css
/*Items menu*/
.user_menu {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

/*Menu header info*/
.display.name {
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #303238;
}

.display.mail {
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #3d5afe;
}

hr.solid {
    border-top: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
    margin: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
}

/*Text Link css*/
.user_menu.item > a {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 8px 0; 
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #75777D;
}

.user_menu.item:hover > a {
    color: #2E323A;
}

/*Icon Menu*/
.icn_menu:before, .icon_menu:after {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-size: 16px
}

.icn_menu {
    margin-right: 10px;
    display: flex !important;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 22px;
    height: 22px;
}

/* User Menu For header website */
.w3-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-content: flex-end;
    align-items: flex-end;
}

.w3-dropdown-click {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 17px;
}

.w3-dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
  min-width: 160px;
  width: 280px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  position:relative;
  animation:animateFromBottom 0.4s
}

@keyframes animateFromBottom {
    from{bottom:-50px;opacity:0} to{bottom:0;opacity:1}
}

@keyframes animateToBottom {
  from{bottom:0;opacity:1} to{bottom:-50px;opacity:0}
}

.w3-show-block,.w3-show {
    display:block!important;
}

.w3-dropdown-content.w3-hide {
  animation:animateToBottom 0.4s
}

.user_menu_button {
    width: 100%;
    background: #fbfbfb!important;
    font-weight: 500!important;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()" class="user_menu_button">Account</button>

<div class="w3-container">
  <div class="w3-dropdown-click">
      
   <div id="Demo" class="w3-dropdown-content w3-bar-block w3-border">
       
    <div class="user_menu header">
        <span class="display name">Hello user</span>
        <span class="display mail">usermail@gmail.com</span>
    </div>   
      
     <hr class="solid">  
     
    <div class="user_menu item">
        <a href="/account">
         <i class="icn_menu fa-regular fa-user">1</i>
         <span class="link_text">Dashboard</span>
        </a>
    </div>
    
     <div class="user_menu item">
        <a href="ordini">
         <i class="icn_menu fa-regular fa-basket-shopping">2</i>
         <span class="link_text">My orders</span>
        </a>
    </div>
    
    <div class="user_menu item">
        <a href="libreria">
         <i class="icn_menu fa-regular fa-cloud-arrow-down">3</i>
         <span class="link_text">Downloads</span>
        </a>
    </div>
    
    <div class="user_menu item">
        <a href="impostazioni">
         <i class="icn_menu fa-regular fa-gear">4</i>
         <span class="link_text">Settings</span>
        </a>
    </div>
    
    <div class="user_menu item">
        <a href="wp-login.php?action=logout">
         <i class="icn_menu fa-regular fa-arrow-right-from-bracket">5</i>
         <span class="link_text">Logout</span>
        </a>
    </div>
   </div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not related to the problem, but you should modernize your code. Use `x.classList.includes()`, `x.classList.add()`, and `x.classList.remove()` instead of string operations.

Comment: I haven't analysed your code in detail or tried to make changes, but the fact that your JS code includes a timeout of 500ms (0.5s) seems significant to me in that this is between 0.4 and 0.6s. I guess the sudden "jump" is a result of this happening 100ms after the CSS animation finishes. Have you tried the 0.4s version while shortening that JS timeout so say 300ms?

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for the advice I appreciate it. Excuse my ignorance, what does it mean to "modernize the code" ? I'm new and I'm trying to learn, could you please explain it to me ?

Comment: @Barmar I followed your advice and I succeeded. Here I opened another question related to the "modernization" of the code, if you can answer I appreciate it very much, thanks.

Comment: @RobinZigmond Your suggestion worked, only I protracted it at 100ms while the ones in the css left at 0.4s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var x = document.getElementById("Demo");
function myFunction() {
    x.classList.toggle('w3-show')
}
```

```css
/*Items menu*/
.user_menu {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

/*Menu header info*/
.display.name {
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #303238;
}

.display.mail {
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #3d5afe;
}

hr.solid {
    border-top: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
    margin: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
}

/*Text Link css*/
.user_menu.item > a {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 8px 0;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #75777D;
}

.user_menu.item:hover > a {
    color: #2E323A;
}

/*Icon Menu*/
.icn_menu:before, .icon_menu:after {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-size: 16px
}

.icn_menu {
    margin-right: 10px;
    display: flex !important;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 22px;
    height: 22px;
}

/* User Menu For header website */
.w3-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-content: flex-end;
    align-items: flex-end;
}

.w3-dropdown-click {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 17px;
}

.w3-dropdown-content {
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index: -10;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #fff;
    min-width: 160px;
    width: 280px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    position:relative;
    top: 30px;
    transition: top .4s, z-index .4s, visibility .4s, opacity .4s;
    opacity: 0;
}

.w3-show {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;

}

.user_menu_button {
    width: 100%;
    background: #fbfbfb!important;
    font-weight: 500!important;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()" class="user_menu_button">Account</button>

<div class="w3-container">
    <div class="w3-dropdown-click">

        <div id="Demo" class="w3-dropdown-content w3-bar-block w3-border">

            <div class="user_menu header">
                <span class="display name">Hello user</span>
                <span class="display mail">usermail@gmail.com</span>
            </div>

            <hr class="solid">

            <div class="user_menu item">
                <a href="/account">
                    <i class="icn_menu fa-regular fa-user">1</i>
                    <span class="link_text">Dashboard</span>
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="user_menu item">
                <a href="ordini">
                    <i class="icn_menu fa-regular fa-basket-shopping">2</i>
                    <span class="link_text">My orders</span>
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="user_menu item">
                <a href="libreria">
                    <i class="icn_menu fa-regular fa-cloud-arrow-down">3</i>
                    <span class="link_text">Downloads</span>
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="user_menu item">
                <a href="impostazioni">
                    <i class="icn_menu fa-regular fa-gear">4</i>
                    <span class="link_text">Settings</span>
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="user_menu item">
                <a href="wp-login.php?action=logout">
                    <i class="icn_menu fa-regular fa-arrow-right-from-bracket">5</i>
                    <span class="link_text">Logout</span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("Demo");
  if (x.className.indexOf("w3-show") == -1) {
    x.className += " w3-show";
  } else { 
    x.className += " w3-hide";
    setTimeout(function(){
    x.className = x.className.replace(" w3-show", "");
      x.className = x.className.replace(" w3-hide", "");
      
    }, 400) // this duration must be like css duration
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, your suggestions both work well. Which advice between the two? Is there a difference?

Comment: Can you give more details please? How is 500 not a proper CSS durations

Comment: I would advise doing on css what can be done on css.
Please check my another answer.

Comment: And 500 is not a proper because you have transition with 400 duration in css
"transition: top .4s, z-index .4s, visibility .4s, opacity .4s;". Your css transition ends over 400ms, and your js delay is 500ms.